# JWPlayer Show image on error

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am using player.onError event handling (JWPlayer 6) to load a error.mp4 video when our livestream is offline or not available.
Problem with this is that the error video is reloaded once it ends which creates 1-2 seconds of loading time and doesn't look good.

I read in few posts in JWPlayer forum that its possible to show a image aswell or even replace the player itself with a custom image in event handling, but none of the posts in forum actually provided the way to do so.

My current code is as follows:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
file: "rtmp://62.210.247.57:1935/live/live",
title: 'OneStream',
});
console.log('Error1');
playerInstance.onError(function(){
console.log('onError');
playerInstance.load({file:"streamError.mp4",image:"http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/7RtXk3vl-480.jpg"});
});
playerInstance.onComplete(function(){
console.log('onComplete');
playerInstance.load({file:"rtmp://62.210.247.57:1935/live/live",image:"http:    //content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/7RtXk3vl-480.jpg"});
});
</script>
```

I want to use a static error.png image so I can use the onBuffer event or such to check the RTMP livestream in realtime and when its online, load it instead.

Comment: According to the [api](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference) `.load` takes either an array or a string, you are passing an object, have you tried `.load([{file:"...",image:"..."}])`

Comment: @PatrickEvans that is working as shown in my example code above, but it loads/plays a video which is working but not what I need, I need just a static image to avoid video buffering/playback/loop

Comment: load needs a file and an image. You could always get the div element that the player loads into, and replace that div with an image, onError, instead.

Comment: I am more into php programming than javascript/DOM, would it be possible for you to post a example code for this ? Also, how about replacing the image with the player again once the stream is available/online again ?